# How to get hyper link reference with a variable in Java

Tags: java, spring

I have a record `User`

```java
public record User(int id, String name, int age, Boolean isMale)
```

I've written a method `getUserById` returning a user with a self referencing link passing  to the method user ID from a path.

```java
    @GetMapping("/users/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<EntityModel<User>> getUserById(@PathVariable("id") int id) throws IOException {
        List<User> users = getUsersFromFile();

        Optional<User> userOptional = users.stream()
                .filter(user -> id == user.id())
                .findAny();

        if (userOptional.isPresent()) {
            User user = userOptional.get();
            Link selfLink = WebMvcLinkBuilder.linkTo(UserController.class)
                    .slash("users")
                    .slash(user.id())
                    .withSelfRel();

            EntityModel<User> entityModel = EntityModel.of(user, selfLink);
            return ResponseEntity.ok(entityModel);
        } else {
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
        }
    }
```

Now I'm trying to write a method `getAllUsers` returning all users with self referencing link for every user and a hyper reference link with id as a parameter, so it would look like

```json
"userById" : {
   "href" : "http://localhost:8080/users?id={id}",
   "templated" : true
   }
```

I've been trying to figure out how I can get that link.

Here's my code which returns a self referencing link for every user but without the parameterized link.

```java
    @GetMapping("/users")
    public ResponseEntity<List<EntityModel<User>>> getAllUsers() throws IOException {
        List<User> users = getUsersFromFile();


        List<EntityModel<User>> userEntityModels = users.stream()
                .map(user -> {
                    Link selfLink = WebMvcLinkBuilder.linkTo(UserController.class)
                            .slash("users")
                            .slash(user.id())
                            .withSelfRel();

                    return EntityModel.of(user, selfLink);
                })
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return ResponseEntity.ok(userEntityModels);
    }
```